# Template field | Exclude filter on basis of template for TreeList and TreelistEx

Tags: sitecore-query, tree-list

Sitecore version: 9.0.2

What I am trying to do:

I have created a template. In one of the fields, I need to have my data type as 'TreeList'/ 'TreelistEx'. 'TreelistEx' is preferred.

The functionality is working fine till the time I am using just the start path, something like

`query:/sitecore/content/Global Repository/Regions`

The moment I try to use the parameters as provided here https://getfishtank.ca/blog/treelist-data-source-hidden-functionality my start items shifts to the root item 'Sitecore'.

I tried using all lower caps in the name. But couldn't crack it.

Few examples which I tried:

- query:/sitecore/content/Global
  Repository/Regions&excludetemplatesfordisplay=Category Folder,Product
  Folder
- query:/sitecore/content/Global
  Repository/Regions&excludetemplatesfordisplay=category folder,product
  folder
- query:/sitecore/content/Global
  Repository/Regions&excludetemplatesfordisplay={332CCC6E-4838-49FA-B11A-8E821E45DB4C}
- query:/sitecore/content/Global
  Repository/Regions&Excludetemplatesfordisplay=country

What I am missing?

Comment: Did you try datasource=/sitecore/content/Global Repository/Regions&...  instead of query:/.... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use either `datasource=` (and not a query). Or a `query:`. You can't mix them. You can't mix additional parameters when using `query:`.

> Unfortunately, as the code is currently implemented, you cannot specify both a query AND parameters to restrict the items.

Source: [Specifying query and parameters for Sitecore Treelist Field Source](https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2016/01/06/specifying-query-and-parameters-for-sitecore-treelist-field-source/)

For your use case however, using `datasource=` will be just fine. You're not actually doing any querying.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt help.